# How does an example of a class change its behavior? Java interface usage

Tags: java, interface, behavior

Easiest to explain with an example.

You have a **Troll** (a class with existing examples) that has to "do something".
It behaves differently according to its Mood.
It sleeps if it is *GoodMood*, it stomps its feet if it is *AngryMood*.
Apparently the Troll can change its Mood (I don't really see how this would be done) and therefore its behavior.

We were told, this had to be done using "interfaces", but I don't see how that could be done.
Obviously really easy to do this using a String or Enum (for cleanliness), but apparently interfaces had to be used.

I got my grade, this isn't homework, just want to know how this could be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
interface Mood{
   behave();
}

class GoodMood implements Mood{
   behave(){
       // behavior for good mood
   }
}


class AngryMood implements Mood{
   behave(){
       // behavior for angry mood
   }
}

class Troll{

    doSomething(Mood m){
         m.behave()
     }
}
```

call using

```
new Troll().doSomething(new AngryMood());
new Troll().doSomething(new GoodMood());
```

**Explanation**

you have a common interface Mood with an unimplemnted behave method. for different type of moods you can implement it. So in your Troll class you just need to pass appropriate mood class. according to the mood the doSomething() method will perform the related tasks

**Benefits**

if you want to add any more mood you do not need to make much changes in the main parts of the code. Just create another class , implement the Mood interface, then use like before

> And they call it [Strategy Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in any of a number of ways, and enums are one of them:

1. define `enum TrollMood`;
2. let it define an abstract `doSomething` method;
3. let it have `GOOD` and `ANGRY` as members;
4. let each member implement `doSomething` appropriately;
5. let the `Troll` class have a property `TrollMood mood`;
6. let `Troll` also have a method `doSomething`, delegating to `mood.doSomething`.

You can throw in an interface in this design, for example you can define `interface TrollBehavior { void doSomething(); }` and have `TrollMood implements TrollBehavior`. The design doesn't ask for it, but if that is the requirement, there is your interface.

Comment: The design might not, but the OP does.

Comment: @DaveNewton Do you think it is not obvious enough how an interface may be thrown into this?

Answer (score 0):

USE **STATE DESIGN PATTERN** TO ACHIEVE THIS OBJECTIVE.